# Binding to Jquery Template data not displaying as I expected

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery templates and I am binding data to the template.
However if I have a string with a space in the word I do not see the entire contents display on the template.

Is there a simple conversion that I'm missing?

For example.

My object:

```
Object {MainText: "ABCD THE MAN", TextOverride: "ABCDTHE MAN", HideFromView: true}
```

My fields:

```
<input type="text" class="group-text" value=${MainText}></>
<input type="text" class="group-text" value=${TextOverride}></>
<input id="Checkbox1" class="hide-in-schedule" type="checkbox" value="${HideFromView}" />
```

However the result looks like this:

```
Group Text: ABCD
Text Override: ABCDTHE
```

Comment: You need to surround the value in the html with quotes.  Like you are for the Checkbox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using quotes on html values:

```
<input type="text" class="group-text" value="${MainText}"></>
<input type="text" class="group-text" value="${TextOverride}"></>
<input id="Checkbox1" class="hide-in-schedule" type="checkbox" value="${HideFromView}" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even catch that they were missing.